# Conservation of momentum gun

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum

When a bullet of mass $m$ exits a gun of mass $M$ with a velocity $v$, the gun moves backward with constant velocity $-{m\over M}v$.
But according of Newton's third law of motion, an equal and opposite force must act on the gun. If an equal *force* acts on gun why does it move back with constant velocity? It should accelerate.

Comment: The gun starts at rest and then accelerates up to final velocity of $-{m\over M}v$.

Answer (score 2):

It does accelerate. The bullet doesn't immediately go from speed $0$ to speed $v$- this process takes time. During that same time, the gun accelerates from $0$ to $-{m\over M}v$.

For many purposes, the time it takes for the bullet to leave the gun is negligible, and so this process can be approximated as being instantaneous. It is never instantaneous in fact, though.

Comment: How can we apply conservation of momentum on rocket gas system if gravitational force (external) acts on system

Comment: In principle, you have to add in the momentum imparted by gravity. In practice, this is often tiny enough to be negligible.

Comment: I don't know what would be momentum imparted on system due to gravity can you tell please

Comment: $mg\Delta t$, mass times the acceleration of gravity times the time interval the force is applied over.

Comment: How momentum is mg(deltaT) because momentum is m*velocity

Comment: $g\Delta T$ has units of velocity

Answer (score 0):

It only moves with constant velocity *after* the firing, just as the bullet also only moves with constant velocity *after* the firing (assuming no atmosphere and gravity and/or negligible time after barrel exit). During the firing, the expanding gas from the powder charge is doing work simultaneously on both the bullet *and* the gun: it is both pushing forward on the bullet, and pushing backward on the gun, and this brings both up to their respective final velocities. The powder gas itself also will have a final velocity and exit the gun, and this contributes to its recoil momentum as well. The release of this gas from the barrel is what produces the loud, ear-dangerous "BANG" sound (the *report* of the gunshot).

Comment: How can we apply conservation of momentum on rocket gas system if gravitational force (external) acts on system

Comment: @user58660 : Yes if there's an external force acting then momentum will not be conserved within the system (but will be conserved in the larger system). The change in total momentum will equal the net external force on the system. But I imagine that in the context of whatever problem would conceive of a gun as "conserving momentum" is in the context of ignoring/compensating that external force.

Answer (score 0):

We know from newton's 2nd law that only an unbalanced force can make an object's momentum change. The gun's initial velocity is 0 and final velocity is -(m/M)v *m/s*. If the gun felt F *N* force then the equation is : 
[image: equation]

So within this Δt time, the velocity is change from 0 to -(m/M)v *m/s*.